# How UINavigationController handle gestures collisions?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to have a solution/reference about how `UINavigationController` handle ,regardless to what he contains, the swipe back gesture and inner components gestures.

For example,
Let's have a `UINavigationController` and a `UITableViewController` inside. When the user press on one of the cells, another `UITableViewController` is push.
Now the user want to pop (back) to the first screen, so he swipe to back and the `UITableViewController` cell is NOT been selected.

How is the `UINavigationController` handle these gesture conflicts (swipe/panning isn't trigger the selected/tap gesture)?

Thanks in advance!